# No space before ORDER BY - Why does this work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across some SQL in an application which had no space before the "ORDER BY" clause.  I was surprised that this even works.

Given a table of numbers, called [counter] where there is simply one column, counter_id that is an incrementing list of integers this SQL works fine in Microsoft SQL Server 2012

```
select
*
FROM [counter] c
where c.counter_id = 1000ORDER by counter_id
```

This also works with strings, e.g.:

```
WHERE some_string = 'test'ORDER BY something
```

My question is, are there any potential pitfalls or dangers with this query?  And conversely, are there any benefits? Other than saving, what, 8 bits of network traffic for that whitespace (whcih may well be a consideration in some applications)

Comment: The scanner manages to read those tokens anyway, independent of space or not. But don't count on it. Later versions may do things differently.

Comment: Not sure but query parser or scanner designed such a way. `select*from tbl` will also work.

Comment: It's not ambiguous as `O` is not a valid part of a number so it can't be part of that and `1000ORDER ` is not a valid column name (unquoted) so `1000` must be a part of a number. But I see only disadvantages of using this.

Comment: I think trying to save network traffic by using that is over-thinking the problem, if you could use a parameterised stored procedure and cut more of it out.

Comment: I guess it works because when they parse the SQL, the designer created a rule that a number ends when a character that cannot be part of a number appears, now that doesn't always mean any non numeric, because . and E and - can appear in numbers, in certain places - the answer is 'it is clever enough to work it out'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain the reason why this works with numbers and strings.

The reason is because numbers cannot start identifiers, unless the name is escaped.  Basically, the first things that happens to a SQL query is tokenization.  That is, the components of the query are broken into identifiers and keywords, which are then analyzed.

In SQL Server, keywords and identifiers and function names (and so on) cannot start with a digit (unless the name is escaped, of course).  So, when the tokenizer encounters a digit, it knows that it has a number.  The number ends when a non-digit character is encountered.  So, a sequence of characters such as `1000ORDER BY` is easily turned into three tokens, `1000`, `ORDER`, and `BY`.

Similarly, the first time that a single quote is encountered, it always represents a string literal.  The string literal ends when the final single quote is encountered.  The next set of characters represents another token.

Let me add that there is exactly zero reason to ever use these nuances.  First, these rules are properties of SQL Server's tokenization and do not necessarily apply to other databases.  Second, the purpose of SQL is for *humans* to be able to express queries.  It is way, way more important that we read them.

Comment: 'The number ends when a non-digit character is encountered' - that isn't right though, it can encounter . or E or even -

Answer (score 0):

As jarlh mentioned there might be difference during scanning and parsing the tokens but it creates correctly during execution plan, hence it might not be huge difference in advantages or disadvantages

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When parser examines characters ,it checks for keywords,identifiers,string constants and match overall semantic and syntactic structure of the language. Since 'Order by' is a keyword and sql parser knows its possible syntactic location in a query, it will interpret it accordingly without throwing any error. This is the reason why your order by will not throw any error.
[Parsing sql query](http://when%20parser%20examines%20characters%20,it%20checks%20for%20keywords,identifiers,string%20constants%20and%20match%20overall%20semantic%20and%20syntatic%20structure%20of%20the%20language.%20Since%20Order%20by%20is%20a%20keyword%20and%20sql%20parser%20knows%20its%20possible%20syntatic%20location%20in%20a%20query,%20it%20will%20interpret%20it%20accordingly%20without%20throwing%20any%20error.)

[Parsing SQL](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/flex-bison/9780596805418/ch04.html)

Comment: it has to pull strings out first, otherwise what about SELECT '* FROM MyTable' [ORDER BY X]

Comment: That should not be an issue since these will be taken care by parser while generating lexical tokens. <http://www.valentina-db.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=valentina:vcomponents:vsql:reference:literals>

Comment: it won't be an issue because it works, but it still has to determine strings before it determines keywords, it can't really start off by spotting keywords